# Package rcpp is not available for (R version 2.15.2) when Working with Shiny

Tags: r, centos, shiny, shiny-server

Here is the message i get, i cannot figure out where to update R to 3.0.0, and resources would help. I Have scoured the web for someone with a clear answer to this exact issue.

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26) -- "Trick or Treat"
Copyright (C) 2012 The R Foundation for Statistical Computin
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
```

```
install.packages('Rcpp', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
# Installing package(s) into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
# (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
# Warning message:
# package ‘Rcpp’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)
```

Comment: Can you download the new version of R from [the website](http://www.r-project.org/)?

Comment: You will either need to update R or install an older version of the Rcpp package (available from `http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/Rcpp`) The latest version requires R 3.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need `Rcpp`, notice the capitalization. Checking the [CRAN page for Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html), it appears Rcpp now requires R 3.0.0 or later. I am on CentOS and have 3.0.2, but unfortunately cannot remember how I updated.

Comment: The error returned actually has it lowercase package ‘rcpp’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)

Comment: Yes, because there is no `rcpp` package, but there is an `Rcpp` package.